# VBA run-time error '1004': cannon access the file

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time posting on here so I apologize for any mistakes I make. As you will see, I am pretty inexperienced with VBA.
My job was to copy an existing macro from one machine to another. So, I copied the entire module into a document then opened on the new machine, added the module to the personal macro workbook. All I have changed from the code is the path, as the destination was obviously changed being on a new machine. I copied the file location from file explorer. When I hit run, I get the following error:

Run-time error '1004':
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
'C:\Users\bookk\Onedrive\Documents\Financials\Payroll Reports\2017-2018**2017-2018\Payroll 17-18\Payroll Reports 17-18\51A35100'**

The path before the bolded portion was copied directly from file explorer. I do not know where the bold portion is coming from or why. My guess is the "if,else,end" statements below. Going to that file location prompts a "does not exist" message, as the actual file location ends before the bolded portion.

Hitting "debug" brings up the following line in yellow. The macro is way longer than what is below but I didn't want this to be longer than it needed (I hope). 
I've looked through several other posts on this site as well as other options but have yet to find a solution. This possibly could have already been answered and I just don't know what i'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub CreatePayrollReport()

    Dim strAnswer As String, intFlag As Integer, strPath As String, intWSWCol As Integer, intWSWRow As Integer

    Dim intWSRCol As Integer, intWSRRow As Integer, intWSWLRow, intNetPayRow, I As Integer

    Dim intWSWSCol As Integer, intWSNPRow, strYearR As String, strYearER As String

    Dim WBWage, WBRep, WSWage, WSRep, WSNetPay

' Set up Parameters

    'intWSWCol = 7       ' 2015.9.15 - old column when QuickBook reports were narrower

    intWSWCol = 9       ' Wage data working column, "Pay" for each person

    intWSWRow = 1

    intWSRCol = 1

    intWSWSCol = 4      ' Wage data gross pay line item description column

    intWSRRow = 5

    intWSNPRow = 5

' Set up Path for Workbooks

    strPath = "C:\Users\bookk\Onedrive\Documents\Financials\Payroll Reports\2017-2018"
The old strPath was "C:\Users\Protected - Bookkeepe\Documents\Bookkeeper\Bookkeeper\2017-2018"

    If Now() > DateSerial(Year(Now()), 9, 5) And Now() <= DateSerial(Year(Now()), 12, 31) Then

        strYearR = Right(Year(Now()), 2) & "-" & Right(Year(Now()) + 1, 2)

        strYearER = Year(Now()) & " - " & Year(Now()) + 1

    Else

        strYearR = Right(Year(Now()) - 1, 2) & "-" & Right(Year(Now()), 2)

        strYearER = Year(Now()) - 1 & " - " & Year(Now())

    End If

    strPath = strPath & strYearER & "\Payroll " & strYearR & "\Payroll Reports " & strYearR & "\"

' Get name of workbook containing wage data

    Do

        strAnswer = InputBox("Please input the name of the workbook that contains the Wage data")

        intFlag = MsgBox("Press OK if this is the correct name - " & strAnswer, vbOKCancel)

    Loop Until intFlag = 1

    Workbooks(strAnswer).Activate

    Set WBWage = ActiveWorkbook

    Set WSWage = Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Get last row of wage data to check

    Columns("B:B").Select

    intWSWLRow = Selection.Find(What:="Adjusted", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _

        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _

        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

' Get Net Pay Row

    Columns("A:A").Select

    intNetPayRow = Selection.Find(What:="Net Pay", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _

        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _

        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

' Get Pay Period Ending Date

    Do

        strAnswer = InputBox("Please the title for this Payroll Report (PP End)")

        intFlag = MsgBox("Press OK if this is the correct name - " & strAnswer, vbOKCancel)

    Loop Until intFlag = 1

    Workbooks.Add

> ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=
strPath & "Pay Period End " & strAnswer & ".xlsx"

    Set WBRep = ActiveWorkbook

    ActiveSheet.Name = strAnswer

    Set WSRep = ActiveSheet

    Set WSNetPay = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Name = "Net Pays"
```

Comment: *strPath = strPath & strYearER & "\Payroll " & strYearR & "\Payroll Reports " & strYearR & "\"* is the line causing the bolded text to be added.  Looks like the year is already in the strPath, then you are adding AGAIN the strYear

Comment: So only that line is important? The If and Else statements aren't a factor? I just don't wanna make changes to the End if statement if I will just create more problems for myself down the road. 
I appreciate the help!

Comment: That is the line that determines the path.  Each part of the bolded statement stem from that line of code.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.